# Is it possible to discard Keycloak user management?

Tags: java, oauth, wildfly, saml, keycloak

I have the hope to use the token generation and management abilities of Keycloak, without authenticating against Keycloak's users but instead, 3rd party systems that do not use token based authorization.

In other words, I want to create a realm that generates tokens not for Keycloak users but for that 3rd party's users, meaning that there is no need to store users in Keycloak's DB.

Is this even possible? If it is could anyone give me some pointers?

From what I've seen the closest ability that Keycloak provides is the Identity Providers option available the Administrator console. Unfortunately and as expected, it works only for OpenID Connect and SAML which of course are token based.

Comment: Keycloak can use custom user storage: http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.0/server_development/topics/user-storage.html. Maybe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like it's exactly what I need. Will look into that and give feedback ASAP